# MatPlotLib: moving plot

Tags: logging

I want to plot a temperature as a function of time. For this I have two linked array:  one for the time value and the other for the temperature. 
The time can be a value ranging from 0 to 24 representing the hours.
The arrays are filled every 4 minutes and I want to forget the very first record taken 24 hours ago. (I using `pop(0)` on both array for doing this)

```
fig_temp = plt.figure(2)

x_temp_arr.append(temps)
y_temp_arr.append(temperature)  

if 1+len(x_temp_arr) > 40/deltat:
  x_temp_arr.pop(0)
  y_temp_arr.pop(0)


plt.title ("outside temperature : " + time.strftime('%d %B %Y') + " / " + str(temperature) + " C")

ax_temp.set_ylim (min(y_temp_arr)- 0.2,max(y_temp_arr) + 0.2)
ax_temp.plot (x_temp_arr,y_temp_arr, color='red', lw=1)

plt.draw()
```

My problem is aldo the arrays are purged (FIFO), the `plt.draw` keep erased records and the plot extend indefinitely.

Any idea why? What would be the solution.

Thanks in advance for the answers.